# Is ||= in Ruby thread safe?

Tags: ruby, thread-safety

Not sure if threads safety even applies to `||=`.

Was originally reading about [ActiveSupport::Memoizable](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/memoizable.rb) and wondered about thread safety there.

Comment: Do you mean "Is it a atomic operation?", "Can there be a delay between testing and assignment", then no, I don't see any such guarantee.

Comment: An assignment is threadsafe if the variable is in a threadsafe place.  So, if you have a global variable then an assignment won't be threadsafe, or, if multiple threads can assign to that variable at the same time.  Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: I guess what I meant to ask was would I get into trouble using `||=` with threads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the implementation. Be aware that `x ||= y` expands to `x || x = y`, and that `x = y` is only executed if `x` is either `false` or `nil`.

With that said, the C implementation of the Ruby language should be completely thread safe.

YARV uses native threads in order to implement concurrency, which *do* run in true parallel. However, in order to maintain backward compatibility, a [global, interpreter-wide lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Interpreter_Lock) was introduced.

JRuby, however, imposes no internal locking on your code, so you *must* manually synchronize your calls when needed.

See [another answer I've given about the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558452/512904) for more details. Also, read [this excellent answer by Jörg W Mittag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57802/512904) for a more in-depth look at the threading models of the various Ruby implementations.

Comment: You said "`x = y` is only executed if `x` is *neither* `false` *nor* `nil`" which is incorrect. `x = y` is only executed if `x` is either `false` or `nil`.

Answer (score 4):

This great post on [thread safety concepts in Ruby](https://lucaguidi.com/2014/03/27/thread-safety-with-ruby/) by Luca Guidi shows that `||=` is not thread-safe (at least in MRI).

Comment: Is this true only only for `@instance` variables?  Or could using `||=` still be safe for method variables if no new threads are created within that method?

Comment: @KelseyHannan theory to understand is that `||=` is not a atomic operation. its basically act as two operations `a = a || b`. mutations of shared variable by multiple treads can lead to a raise condition.