# How do I apply a ruby memoization pattern to code this code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, memoization

I am upgrading an app from Rails 3.2.11 to 3.2.17 and I'm getting the following error message:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActiveSupport::Memoizable is deprecated and will be removed in future releases, simply use Ruby memoization pattern instead.
```

I know what memoization is, and the offending code appears to be the following:

```
def api
  @client.vm_by_name(name) if cluster
end
memoize :api
```

I'm not quite sure how to memoize this using a ruby memoization pattern. The previous techs have memoized the `api` method. Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
def api
  @api ||= @client.vm_by_name(name) if cluster
end
```

Note on [thread safety](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853086/is-in-ruby-thread-safe).