# Ruby why are class instance variables threadsafe

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9558452/818951) answer they are, but then the poster states that things work differently in JRuby so I am confused?

I am implementing a multi tenancy solution using class instance variables, so it doesn't matter what Ruby implementation or web server I am using, I need to make sure that data cannot be leaked.

Here is my code:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.current_tenant=(tenant)
    @tenant = tenant
  end

  def self.current_tenant
    @tenant
  end
end
```

What do I need to do to make sure that no matter what happens (changing Ruby implementation, changing web server, new Ruby threading capabilities etc) that my code is thread safe?

Comment: tenancy is an attribute of the machine? the session? the request?

Comment: The tenant is set in the url, so it is an attribute of the request

Comment: So it does not make sense to set it as a _class_ variable - it would affect the entire system (or process to be exact) - not just the request

Comment: So once Rails has loaded, all requests will set the same instance variable (same as in memory location)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the tenancy attribute's scope is a request, I would suggest you keep it in the scope of the current *thread*. Since a request is handled on a single thread, and a thread handles a single request at a time - as long as you always set the tenancy at the beginning of the request you will be fine (for extra security, you might want to un-assign the tenant at the end of the request).

To do this you can use [thread local](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Thread.html#class-Thread-label-Thread+variables+and+scope) attributes:

```
class Tenant < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.current_tenant=(tenant)
    Thread.current[:current_tenant] = tenant
  end

  def self.current_tenant
    Thread.current[:current_tenant]
  end

  def self.clear_current_tenant
    Thread.current[:current_tenant] = nil
  end
end
```

Since this is using a thread store, you are totally thread safe - each thread is responsible for its own data.

Comment: What if I wanted to memoize results of some heavy function. Do I need to use Thread.current or I can continue using instance variable of the class on JRuby? Is there chance that heavy function will be called more than once?

Comment: @Zhomart - nothing prevents a heavy function from being called more than once on different threads, one might argue that there is a _greater_ chance for that, since the function takes longer to finish, so there is more chance that one is already running...

Comment: I recently used a class instance variable to memoize a heavy function and as soon as I deployed to production (using nginx) everything went wrong, every page refresh the data changed with a different model data (and I could pinpoint the issue to the memoization). I then moved the memoization to an instance method on the model and everything worked fine. Why is that since class instance variables should be thread safe as well?

Comment: @sandre89 - there is hardly enough information to help you, you should ask a new question, with you code, and all the details to get an adequate response. My guess is, though, that your problems have nothing to do with thread safety.