# Hash read/write thread-safe on key

Tags: ruby, jruby

Let's assume I have hash like:

`@@foo = { 1 => 2, 2 => 3, 3 => 4}`

If I want to change value of key 1 do I have to use Mutex that it's used for whole read/write protection or Mutex object which is defined for key 1 write/reads ?

I could not find detailed concept apart of that using Mutex is necessary.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Thread Safety: Class Variables in Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9558192/thread-safety-class-variables-in-ruby)

Comment: @WandMaker it's not the question for general thread safety but rather safety if parallel access to different parts of hash

Comment: Mutation of Hash is same as Mutation of any other class level object....right?

Comment: Not really - if you eg mutate string there is a big chance to mess up without mutex. But if every thread modify only one key in hash - is there any chance to break anything?

Comment: what you need is a read-write lock http://ruby-concurrency.github.io/concurrent-ruby/master/Concurrent/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html